# MySQL ORDER of alphanumeric strings, priority to numbers then trailing non numeric characthers

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have this problem. A column in MySQL DB has data as following:
1
10
100
102
1020
1022
1023
1024
1025
1025A
1026A
.
.
.

I Obtained correct numeric sorting with a query like this:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT LPAD(ubicazione, 8, '0') FROM t_ubicazione ORDER BY LPAD(ubicazione, 8, '0') ASC;
```

that give me this result:

```
00000001 00000017 00000018 00000019 0000001A 0000001B 0000001M 0000001S 00000021 00000022
```

My problem is that 0000001A should be after 00000001, so correct order should be:

```
00000001
0000001A
0000001B
0000001M
0000001S
00000017
00000018
00000019
00000021
00000022
```

how can I obtain this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the numeric part of the column as an integer number with an implicit conversion `ubicazione + 0` and sort by that first and then `ubicazione`:

```
SELECT ubicazione 
FROM t_ubicazione 
ORDER BY ubicazione + 0, ubicazione;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=373fb750fa8609bc303ccbaa0496a5f9).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ubicazione
FROM t_ubicazione
ORDER BY CAST(ubicazione AS UNSIGNED), ubicazione